# What is the exact difference between Windows Azure and Windows IIS?

Tags: iis, azure

I have finished developing a webapplication on Visual Studio 2012 along with Microsoft SQL 2008. I'm trying to make it a "live" webapp which can be accessed through the phone rather than a localhost.

I researched and found 2 solutions which are

1. IIS
2. Azure

I have been looking all over the net for various clear explaination of the main difference between IIS and Azure. From my understanding, IIS is a web server application that comes with Windows Server and is used to serve up web sites while Azure is a Windows hosting solution that utilizes IIS. In that case why do people still uses IIS while Azure provide both a cloud platform and IIS?

Which is also better to host any typical web-application that used to run on the localhost?

I can't seems to find any thread in SO or ASP.Net forum which can clearly explain the main difference between the two along with the advantage and disadvantage.

Here are some of the [link1](http://forums.iis.net/p/1199379/2052100.aspx/1?Difference%20between%20IIS%20and%20Windows%20Azure%20), [link2](http://kevinhoffman.sys-con.com/node/1095058/mobile) i have found that provide brief information about the two.

Comment: All of your questions can be answered by just visiting Azure and read it's help section.

Comment: i dont think i can find the answered here. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/faq/
this is the link for the help section in azure.

Comment: Which question can't you find an answer for? And did you read the "web sites" documentation? It got it's own FAQ which in detail explains how "web sites" work in Azure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually a place to run your web application, Teo.

As you've found, you can do that in IIS if you have a server that is connected to the Internet. A way to get such a server is to either got to a hosting company or just use the Windows Azure cloud as you've found as well.

One of the simplest ways for you to do this right now and for free is to sign up for a Windows Azure trial account. As part of that account you get a basic, shared Windows Azure Website for free.

Here are the links you need:

(1) http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/

(2) http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

I would strongly recommend that you go through the entire tutorial (1) step-by-step before trying to do this with your own application. Before you start, sign up for a trial account (2). You will not be charged in the first month and you will not be charged if you stick with the free website.

Enjoy.

Comment: May i ask this free website is my very own first website or microsoft free demo website? In VS2012, there's an option to publish my own webapp into windows azure. I already have a Free Azure account though. As for now, I'm a student using my lab's computer with IIS However, it is my first time trying it out on my own, hence i got a little confused with it.

Comment: If you have an azure account, just follow the tutorial. The result of that will be a website that you own and manage and that people can call, it's not just a demo. As long as you stick with the 'free' tier you won't be charged, but you can write your own apps. Details on what's in 'free' are here:  http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/

Comment: However my main question isn't about the pricing now. It's about the main difference between Azure and IIS and theit definition. and what is their advantage and differences over each other.

Comment: Windows Azure runs IIS. You write an ASP.NET app that runs inside IIS and that may be hosted on top of Windows Azure. Do the tutorial.

Comment: May i ask where do you get such tutorial? If i'm not wrong, windows azure basically do everything for you in order to keep your website up in the cloud in a online status for people to access view their phone.

Comment: Yes, Windows Azure will do all that. I'm referring to the tutorial I linked to. Follow all the steps in the document to gain some insight in how this all works: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/ - before you've gone through that there's little to gain by asking more theoretical questions, Teo

Comment: Note that if you get a regular server you can install IIS on it and configure it yourself. If you go with a hosted solution you may not be able to access IIS in the same way. Typically they will have an abstracted website that allows you to configure IIS options. What's happening behind the scenes is that website is using an API to set IIS options. The hosted solutions are easier to use and are usually cheaper. In other words one solution gives you remote desktop to do whatever you want and the other gives you an admin webpage to configure your site.

Answer (score -5):

Comparing IIS to Azure is irrelevant. Those are two different concepts, which are vaguely related to each other. You lack some very basic understanding of what each one means, and I recommend you to go and read about each them from scratch.

IIS is indeed a web server application. That means, for example, that it can rout HTTP request and responds to and from the web site application that you have created. 
To keep it simple, let's say that IIS can run on any Windows machine, which makes the machine a Web Server.

If you want to have your web site up and running, you need either have your own machine that acts as a web server, or either upload your web site application to some other machine.

Azure is a group of [cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) services. One of the services is a Web Site Host, that allows you to use cloud computers to run the IIS that hosts your web site.
As part of the service, Azure will take care of installing and using the IIS server for you.

Bottom line, if you are going the Windows path, you will probably end up using Both Azure and IIS (unless you will want to self host your web site...)